# How to print to file in AMPL? `option log_file` doesn't work

Tags: file, printing, io, ampl

I want to use some `printf` to print to a file.

I can use

```
for{i in set1}  printf '%10.5f\n',var1[i] >> ('a' & 'very' & 'long' & 'string' & 123 & sprintf('%5d', foo));
for{i in set2}  printf '%10.5f\n',var2[i] >> ('a' & 'very' & 'long' & 'string' & 123 & sprintf('%5d', foo));
for{i in set3}  printf '%10.5f\n',var3[i] >> ('a' & 'very' & 'long' & 'string' & 123 & sprintf('%5d', foo));
```

But I don't want to repeat the file each time.

It seems `option log_file` should do the trick, but doesn't work for me: the file is created but empty, and the output is printed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered that I must change `option log_file` after printing, because it seems that AMPL doesn't close the file, even if I use `close`.

Then, the following works:

```
print "Hello, ";              # Printed to the console
option log_file "test.txt";
print "World";                # Printed to the console and file
option log_file ""; 
close;
```

Comment: Well, on my machine, it works just fine without the `close;`.

Comment: @Ali I use windows XP and without `option log_file ""; close;` the produced file is empty and I can't rename or delete it because it's in use by ampl.exe. Which OS do you use?

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I am on Linux. But it's probably not the OS. Could you try running the `ampl.exe your_model.mod` in the command line? In this way ampl.exe exits after running the model and the log file cannot be used by ampl.exe anymore.

Comment: @Ali I have tried the console (I was using amplide) and the file is not printed until I use `exit;`, and then `ampl: exit;` appears at the end of the logfile.

Comment: It is either an AMPL quirk or a Windows bug. If the `close;` command solves it for you then I say there is no point in investigating it any further.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid repeating the file name, store it in a parameter:

```
param out symbolic =
  'a' & 'very' & 'long' & 'string' & 123 & sprintf('%5d', foo);
for{i in set1} printf '%10.5f\n',var1[i] >> (out);
for{i in set2} printf '%10.5f\n',var2[i] >> (out);
for{i in set3} printf '%10.5f\n',var3[i] >> (out);
```

Note that the parentheses around `out` are important, because they allow passing an expression (a parameter reference in this case) rather than verbatim text as a file name.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like that but AMPL tried to convert the string to a number and threw errors.